# How to enable port 25 in oracle cloud instance?

Tags: smtp, cloud, port, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, smtp-auth

I want to setup a SMTP server in my oracle instance which is running windows server 2012. For that i need to open port 25 in my VPS .
How can i enable port 25 in my VPS ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this blog on setting up of your SMTP server in Windows Server 2012: [setting up of your SMTP server in Windows Server 2012](https://blog.powerbiz.net.au/exchange/how-to-set-up-an-internal-smtp-service-for-windows-server-2012-essentials/).

And after this is done you need to add the ingress/egress rules in the Oracle Cloud security list and Network security group (if any). Please refer this for more details on OCI security list [Security List](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/securitylists.htm#:%7E:text=A%20security%20list%20consists%20of,Lists%20and%20Network%20Security%20Groups.) and [Network security group](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/networksecuritygroups.htm).

I hope you have configured the VCN with subnets with proper route entries. Please refer this document of more details on [route tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingroutetables.htm).